# Embed parameter value as stash value

Tags: stash

How can I use a stash variable that has been stored up in the template as a value for an embed parameter further down?

```
{embed="template/_include" email="{exp:stash:get name="email"}"}
```

Obviously at the moment I am hitting some parse issues but I don't know how to rectify.

Answer (score 1):

If you must use an EE embed rather than a Stash embed, then the easiest approach would be to set a global ("snippet") variable rather than a Stash variable:

```
{exp:stash:set name="email" type="global"}My email address{/exp:stash:set}
```

Than reference it in your embed template like so

```
{email}
```

Alternatively, use a Stash embed:

```
{exp:stash:set name="email"}My email address{/exp:stash:set}

{stash:embed:my_include}
```

Then reference the variable in the Stash embed like so:

```
{stash:email}
```